# Could someone be liable if they intentionally congregate after testing positive for coronavirus?

Tags: united-states, liability, murder

As I understand it, in most states it's a criminal act to knowingly engage in unprotected sex if you know you have a sexually-transmitted disease and don't inform your partner. If the disease is life-threatening (like HIV/AIDS), this could rise to attempted murder.

Are these laws specific to STDs, or do they extend to any life-threatening, infectious disease?

For instance, suppose a political candidate found out that they'd tested positive for coronavirus. But they didn't inform the public, and continued to hold campaign rallies where they didn't wear a mask and discouraged the audience from wearing one. Or they participated in a debate where the other participants weren't wearing masks. If any of the audience members or debate participants become infected, would the candidate be liable?

Or if they continue working in close proximity with their office and campaign staff without informing them of the danger, and staffers catch COVID-19, would this be considered a criminal act?

Does someone actually have to catch the disease? Or is it enough that the person knows they're endangering the people around them?

Comment: Related, maybe duplicate: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/50156/can-rand-paul-be-sued-for-negligent-transmission-of-covid-19 and https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/50356/criminal-transmission-of-covid-19-knowingly-exposing-vulnerable-individuals?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @NateEldredge The second one is similar, although it's about trying to infect a specific person as opposed to exposing large groups. The Rand Paul one seems less so, since he didn't know if he was infected, he was still waiting for test results.